# Dump dict directly to file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Is it possible to do something like this with the `json` module?

```
>>> import json
>>> d={1:2}
>>> json.dump(d, 'file.json')
```

Or, do I need to use `json.dumps` and then `file.write` ? That is:

```
>>> open('file.json', 'w').write(json.dumps(d))
```

Comment: Did you read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?

Comment: `open('file.json', 'w').write(json.dumps(d))` don't  do this. Don't be swayed by people packing things into 1 line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)
```

**Explanation:**

In the second line, `file.json` gets created and opened as the variable f.

In the third line, your dictionary `d` gets written into the file.json